# How to style nested components in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I coded a table of content using nested components. Each component is a list of headers.

I want to style each component with an indentation effect (margin-left: "20px") to differentiate each level of nesting.

Example:

```
<Parent> 
-->indent <Child/>
 -->indent   <Child2/>
   -->indent    (etc.)
</Parent>
```

Any idea of how to do it dynamically?

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";

const TocContent = ({ props }) => {
    return (
        <div className="TOC">
            {props.TOC.map((header) => (
                <HeaderList key={header.objectId} header={header} props={props} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const HeaderList = ({ header, props }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <li
                onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                className="listing"
                style={{}}
                onClick={(e) =>
                    props.handleHeaderClick(
                        header.level,
                        header.treepath,
                        header.containsLaw,
                        header.sections,
                        header.secNum,
                        header.objectId,
                        header.id,
                        e.stopPropagation(),
                    )
                }
            >
                {header._id}
            </li>
            {/* // if savedIndex === CurrentParent Index */}
            {props.headerIndex === header.objectId &&
                props.headers2.map((node2) => (
                    <HeaderList key={node2.objectId} header={node2} props={props} />
                ))}
            {props.headerIndex2 === header.objectId &&
                props.headers3.map((node3) => (
                    <HeaderList key={node3.objectId} header={node3} props={props} />
                ))}
            {props.headerIndex3 === header.objectId &&
                props.headers4.map((node4) => (
                    <HeaderList header={node4} key={node4.objectId} props={props} />
                ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default TocContent;
```

Comment: Is there any issue with using CSS class selectors? Such as `Parent > Child1 > Child2 {...}`. Naturally you'll need to select via the rendered html instead of attempting to select the components.

Comment: Not sure why, but in the console, I get "unsupported property value" when I tried. The margin-left property is strikethrough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the margin (or padding) on the element that contains both the `HeaderList`'s main content and the sub-`HeaderList` components (instead of just the main content as you have now). Specifically this would be the `div` that wraps all other returned content in the `HeaderList` component. The margins will stack up and each nested header list will be more indented than the parent.

For example (just HTML & CSS):

```css
.header-list {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-list">
  First Element
  <div class="header-list">
    Second Element
    <div class="header-list">
      Third Element
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't make it works. I added a className or directly with styling and nothing happen. Do you have an example in React (instead of Html)?Thanks

Comment: @Dom355, which HTML element did you give the className to?

Comment: Works great. I apologize, I made a mistake implementing your solution in my CSS file.